# Update existing foreign key values using eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to update multiple rows of data with existing foreign key values where `basket` should only link to the foreign ID of `100`.

Example:

| id | title | basket_id (foreign key to another table) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 100 |
| 2 | banana | 200 |
| 2 | kiwi | 300 |

What I have tried:

```
$fruits = Fruit::whereIn('basket', [200, 300])->get();

foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
  $fruit->update([
    "basket_id" => 100
  ])
}
```

This works fine, however, when I print `$fruit`, I am still getting the old `basket_id` in the `relations` attribute in eloquent.

Am I missing a step?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch it, you can use the `fresh()` or `refresh()` on `$fruit` object, like this:

```php
$fruits = Fruit::whereIn('basket', [200, 300])->get();

foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
  $fruit->update([
    "basket_id" => 100
  ]);
  $fruit->refresh(); // Fetch updated object
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#refreshing-models

> The `fresh` method will re-retrieve the model from the database. The existing model instance will not be affected:
>
> ```
> $flight = Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
> $freshFlight = $flight->fresh();
> ```
>
> The `refresh` method will re-hydrate the existing model using fresh data from the database. In addition, all of its loaded relationships will be refreshed as well:
>
> ```
> $flight = Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
> $flight->number = 'FR 456';
> $flight->refresh();
> $flight->number; // "FR 900"
> ```

Comment: Thank you, do I need to a save() after?

Comment: No. `update()` method already performs a save operation

Comment: I see, what does `refresh()` do? does it do any updates to the DB?

Comment: `refresh()` method is used to reload the entire model instance and its relationships from the database, discarding any changes made to the model instance.

Comment: When you call `$fruit->refresh()`, eloquent will reload the entire `$fruit` object from the database, along with its related object. @cafe123